# Error when calling request binary, system exit code: 126, text output, Error when calling response binary, system exit code: 126, text output:

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm using a prestashop version 1.6.1.1 for my site and im using "tggatos SIPS/ATOS" module for payements.

After migrating my site to a new server i got some errors because of which the payment module is not working :

1. Error when calling request binary, system exit code: 126, text output:
2. Error when calling response binary, system exit code: 126, text output:

I would be very grateful for any advice or suggestion on how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue you have to make sure, that those files are actually binaries. If you've transferred them i.e. by filezilla ftp client then transfer is not in binary mode by default.

Unpack them directly from archive on server or change transfer settings should resolve that issue.